# Where to get good music for corporate videos?

Tags: music

I'd like to find out your go to places for music to license or royalty free for corporate videos. I find it takes ages to find music that actually comes close to what I need..
Any good links?

Cheers,

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to recommend [audioblocks](https://www.audioblocks.com/).

Audioblocks is a subscription based site, with some impressive benefits

- Unlimited downloads
- 100% Royalty-Free
- Yours to keep forever
- They have a wide selection of tracks, sound effects, loops and more

> I find it takes ages to find music that actually comes close to what I need..

Audioblocks also has a **very powerful** search, where you can search by Moods, Genres, Instruments, Tempo, Duration, etc. This will help you find what you are looking for a lot faster than scrolling through several free music sites.

Consider using my [referral link](http://audioblocks.refr.cc/KD9KXBT) to get a discount on the membership.
P.S. I am NOT in any way affiliated with audioblocks.

Answer (score 1):

You should approach local recording studios and music production houses. A lot of them will have some sort of showreel and a shelf of original music. Some also offer CD's of copyright free music for a fair price. A quick google search in your local area should dig some out. My own company [Broadwood Music Productions](http://www.broadwoodmusic.com) does this but I strongly advocate supporting creative writers in your local area.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the YouTube music in your account admin section? They have lots of music that would suit your needs I would think.

Comment: Does YouTube license agreement allow for use outside of YouTube?

Answer (score 0):

Copied straight from my free music bookmarks folder:

- [incompetech](http://incompetech.com/). Great background music, all available for free under the [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/) license. You will probably have heard many of the songs on that site on YouTube before.
- [musopen](https://musopen.org/). Royalty-free performances of classical music under varying licences. Low-quality versions for free, HD versions available for fees.
- [freepd](http://freepd.com/). A rather large collection of [Public Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain) tracks. I would be cautious and try to find the original uploaders for any piece you are interested in using.
- [purple planet](http://www.purple-planet.com/). Both free and paid royalty free music for different moods/genres.
- [ccMixter](http://dig.ccmixter.org/). Seems to have changed a lot since I last used the site. Looks like they still got CC-licensed content, but I would read up on their terms of use first.
- [jamendo](https://www.jamendo.com). Also not quite how I remember them. They still have royalty-free music it appears, but do watch out for what licence the tricks you are interested in are distributed under.
- [Cayzland Music](https://www.cayzland-music.de/). Free for private use, commercial use required licensing, but seems to be legit and easy-to understand.
- [danosongs](http://www.danosongs.com/). A musician who licences his songs for 10 bucks per song apparently. Not a bad deal.
- [Bensound](http://www.bensound.com/). Some great tunes available under the CC-BY-ND licence. Depending on your needs you will need to pay a licence fee, make sure to check out the licensing page.
- [YouTube Audio Library](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music). The YouTube audio library. Last time I checked, I wasn't able to find clear and concise licence terms, and information on whether you are allowed to use those tracks outside of YouTube. I would be slightly wary when using them for commercial products.

You can find more royalty-free content using the search engines available at [CC search](https://search.creativecommons.org/). You can also use the [Google advanced search](https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search) directly (note the last dropdown menu, *usage rights*). There's tons of musicians out their who make their music available for no or little money using liberate licences, either on web portals such as the ones mentioned above or on their own personal sites.You just have to look for them.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am not responsible for the content on any of the linked sites. Remember that just because someone uploads music to a website and claims it's free-to-use, it doesn't mean he actually has the right to do so or the authority to grant you any rights to it. And if you use a copyrighted piece of music in your project without knowing any better, you can stil be held responsible even if you downloaded it from a website that claimed it was free. Always check if the website you are downloading from is legit and if the uploaders actually have to rights to the music (in most cases, that means they made it themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Pond5. It's expensive but you have full rights afterwards.